# Karate Condition Update For XML

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where I am reading an xml file.
* def inputXml = read('/src/test/resoursces/sample.xml)

below is the content of my xml file

```
<request>
<header>
<node>
<p n="CURRENCY">USD</p>
<p n="VALUE">1000</p>
<node>
<header>
<request>
```

Based on a test condition I want to remove XML node.

My script is like below

```
* eval if ( <CURRENCY> == 'ABC') karate.remove(inputXml,'request/header/node/p[@n=CURRENCY')
```

1. I am facing two issues am not able to update the xml, when the eval condition is satisfied I get an error like "invalid variable name"

2.Will I be able to escape p[@n="CURRENCY" double quotes inside expression coz I think thats the correct path to the xml node?

Comment: please have the courtesy to make the xml well-formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
* if (true) karate.remove('inputXml', "/request/header/node/p[@n='CURRENCY']")
```

Comment: Thanks peter, couldn't copy paste the actual xml i was typing , sorry about that. The above solution worked!!